# C# и MySQL. Ошибка "Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных, windows

Добрый день. Возникла проблема. При подключению к базе данных, в коде стало выдаваться исключение `"Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"`. Немного поискав решение в гугле, я понял, что эта ошибка выдаётся, когда нет прав для доступа к определённому серверу. У меня сервер стоит на  `localhost`. Казалось бы, можно просто дать определённые права юзеру и всё. Но к серверу я обращаюсь от пользователя `root`. Все нужные права даны. Да и к тому же, всё почему-то раньше нормально работало. Не знаю что делать. Я в тупике. Пробовал переустановить MySql сервер, но результат тот же. Так  же создавал ещё одного пользователя, давал все возможные права ему. Обращался к бд от его имени. Результат тот же. MySQL server 5.7.

Comment: Вы подключаетесь к серверу `localhost` или `127.0.0.1`? В базе какие есть пользователи с именем root? `root@localhost`, `root@127.0.0.1`, `root@%`? Чему равно значение `name_resolve` в настройках сервера?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov подключаюсь  к localhost,  базе есть пользователи с именем root@localhost.  Где можно посмотреть значение name_resolve?

Comment: `skip-name-resolve` в конфиге сервера или командной строке запуска сервера https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Стоит значение OFF.

Comment: Покажите как Вы подключаетесь к базе

Comment: @AntonShchyrov  Вот так:
`connection_string = "server=localhost;SslMode=none;user=root;database=test;port=3306;password=0000";
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connection_string);`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov потом `connect.Open();`

Comment: просто `mysql.exe --host=localhost --user=root --password=0000` коннектится к серверу?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov через консоль коннектится.

Comment: Идеи закончились :((